# How to make a custom color picker in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm trying to make a custom color picker, I should have everything I need to fill in the image with the colors. When I run the program it displays nothing only a the widget w/o colors that I can move to the left or top.

I added the QWidget in the designer tab, promoted it to the new class I made named, "ColorPicker". I added a protected function paintEvent in my header file.

My CPP file of ColorPicker:

```
#include "colorselector.h"

ColorSelector::ColorSelector(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void ColorSelector::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
    QColor c;
    QImage pic(360,20,QImage::Format_RGB32);
    for(int x=0; x < 360; x++){
       for(int y=0; y < 20; y++){
           c.setHsl(x,255,127);
           pic.setPixel(x,y,c.rgb());
           }
     }
}
```

My header file of ColorPicker:

```
#ifndef COLORSELECTOR_H
#define COLORSELECTOR_H

#include <QWidget>

class ColorSelector : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ColorSelector(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // COLORSELECTOR_H
```

It should give me a rainbow of colors in a QWidget.

Comment: I edited it, so I basically get nothing in my window. I only get the widget w/o colors that I can move to the side or top of the window.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `pic` you colored in.

Comment: Use [`QPainter::drawImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage) to paint the image you coloured. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) you have an example of how to use `QPainter` to draw an image (look into `ScribbleArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` implementation).

Answer (score 0):

This is not what do you exactly want but may show you a good vision for doing that.
you can have three  [QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html) which represent 3 main colors red green and blue the value of sliders should be ranged between 0 to 255 for each of them.

Then create a square Qlabel and paint the backgroundColor of it by css with sliders value something like this :

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel;
label->->setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(slider1->value();,sliderGreen->value();,slideBlue->value(););");
```

Dude it just a concept of the code and its not really code please reWrite it not paste it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

in the color selector you can paint the background of the widget using the r,g,b,a from a Qslider for example

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e) {
    QPainter painter{this};
    //and now fill the background!
    painter.setBrush(QColor(r.value(), g.value(), b.value(), a.value()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this custom Circular Color Picker for PyQt

[Circular PyQt ColorPicker](https://github.com/omega0verride/PyQt-ColorPicker)

[It looks like this and can easily added as a Widget and modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYy14.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.